# How to call Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() after login is made in another component?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I have AppBar component which I want to show currently logged in user. On the same page I have Profile component, which triggers login form. The problem is that they are not synched, obviously currentAuthenticatedUser inside AppBar is called before login is made and not called after, unless page is refreshed:

```
function AppBar() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((u) => {
        setUser(u.username);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div>AppBar: {user}</div>
}

function Profile(props: any) {
    return <Authenticator>
      {({ user, signOut }: any) => {
        return <>
          <div>Profile: { user.username }</div>
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
          </>
      }}
    </Authenticator>
}

function App() {
  return <b><AppBar /><Profile /></b>
}
```

[image: Step 1: AppBar is loaded and username is not yet populated, because we're in the middle of log in]

After login:

[image: Step 2: Login is done, Profile component has loaded user info, but AppBar is not synched]

After page refresh:

[image: Step 3: After hitting Refresh, AppBar loads username]

How to display username in AppBar right after login without the need to refresh the page? Thanks!

Comment: I have this implemented using context in a global state for the user data, then all views dependant of the user data will be updated on users data loaded or removed

Comment: Thanks @Woohaik, where do you set users data? Is there a "logged in" event in Authorizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution borrowed from [here](https://github.com/pdichone/amplify-appsync-blog-course/blob/main/pages/components/navbar.js)

```
function AppBar() {
  const [signedUser, setSignedUser] = useState<{username: string}>();
  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  }, []);

  async function authListener() {
    Hub.listen("auth", (data) => {
      switch (data.payload.event) {
        case "signIn":
          return setSignedUser(data.payload.data);
        case "signOut":
          return setSignedUser(undefined);
      }
    });

    try {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      setSignedUser(user);
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  return <div>AppBar: {signedUser?.username}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that functionality by either using local state or context

1. Local state:

setup your `const [user, setUser] = useState();` hook on top of `AppBar` and `Profile` components. Then pass down `user` as prop on the `AppBar` component and pass down `setUser` on the `Profile` component, you would need to create an internal component inside `Profile` that would take this prop and then be rendered inside the `Authenticator` component.

2. Context:

It is a similar process as above but you need to use the `React.createContext(<<context_data_here>>)` syntax. I would suggest using this approach if your app need access to `user` on many components. If that is not the case using local state is recommended.

If you are not familiar with context I'd suggest watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc)

Comment: Yes, that's how I can propagate the user, but how do I set it up? Is there a loggedIn event inside <Authenticator>? Or I just call it inside the callback before return?

Comment: you can render another component in the authenticator after return and then pass the `setUser` function in that component